# App for statistics of my personal emails usage

Tags: web-development, email

Is it exists kind of app that can calculate my usage of emails

for example:

1. get number of sending emails per day/month
2. number of receiving
3. size of all emails
4. ...

if not, i think it will be interesting app! :)

Comment: What email client are you using? What operating system? Or do you want to use it directly on your IMAP data?

Comment: yes, i wanna use it directly on pop/imap

Answer (score 0):

Xobni for Outlook does this and it's a free plugin.

http://www.xobni.com/learnmore/

"**Fun email stats**"

Xobni creates fun and revealing statistics to share with your friends and coworkers. Say "thanks" to the person inside your company that responds to you fastest. Or, tell the person that responds the slowest, "Thanks for nothing!" See who sends you the most email within your company — or across all of your email contacts.

Comment: not good, tried it before and it eat my mamory. what i need is simple web based app with numbers. looks like idea for a small startup :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site that has a number of tools that you can choose from that would give you the web based reporting you are looking for.

http://www.slipstick.com/exs/reporting.asp